# Communication between server and client

Tags: ruby, sockets

Been following this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm (couldn't find a more complete one)

I got it up and running. Except I don't know how to make the client send a message to the server (and respond to it) and viceversa. How do I achieve that?

There are many docs but none of them seem to detail about this.

Comment: What do you have done so far?

Comment: I used .write and .send methods from the client (on the TCPSocket instance), and "nothing" seems to happen. Perhaps the server is indeed receiving a message, but I don't know how to respond to it.

Also, after using those methods, it crashes (apparently the connection was forced to be closed).

Comment: Are you `read`ing or `gets`ing the data on the other side?